# Как обратиться к зуму браузера?

Tags: браузер, javascript

Хочу сделать так, что при открытии страницы, она открывалась как будто пользователь сам увеличил страницу через "ctr+" до 300%.

Возможно обратиться к зуму браузера через JS, если "да" то как?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте:

```
document.body.style.zoom = 3
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает но не везде: chrome, safari, IE7, IE8, IE9(небольшой баг горизонтальная полоса прокрутки появилась, но она убирается через body{overflow:hidden}) А вот Opera и Mozilla не хотят zoomировать

Comment: onload="javascript:document.body.style.zoom=2.905" (при 2.905 - 300px становится 900px) к body добавляется стиль style="zoom:2.905" а опера и мозила этот зум не обрабатывают да и IE не совсем коректно себя ведет

Comment: вообщем это не то, что я хотел